# python 3 logic error got me all messed up

Tags: python, logic

Okay, I'm working on a project for class, and I'm stuck on this logic error. I've noted the rest of the original errors after I fixed them in my code...and I feel like I know where the logic error is. I'm just unsure how to fix it. Can I get some help?

Thanks in advance.

```
import random

def display_title():
    print("Guess the number!")
    print()

def set_limit():
    print("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: ")
    limit = int(input())
    return limit

def count(): ## had to add count being defined as below it was unrecognized by python. 
    count +=1

def play_game(limit):
    global count
    number = random.randint(1, limit)
    print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
    while True:
        guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        if guess < number:
            print("Too low. ")
            count ## See def count
        elif guess >= number:
            print("Too high. ")
            count ## See def count
        elif guess == number: ## Pretty sure my logic error is here <---- 
            print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
            return 

def main(): ## syntax error, no : was here
    display_title()
    again = "y"
    while again.lower() == "y":
        limit = set_limit()
        play_game(limit) ## limit wasn't set inside, causing a missing positional argument 
        again = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
        print()
    print("Bye!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You do not need to use `print()` to print an empty line.
- You can prompt the user using `input` no need to have a separate `print` statement before.
- `count` can be defined within `play_game` and it should initialized to `1` rather than the default `0` because even if the user guesses on the first try they had 1 guess.
- `elif guess >= number:` needs to be changed to `elif guess > number:`
- If the first character of `answer` converted to lowercase equals `y` you can call `main()` again to restart the game.

I fixed the above issues in the code below:

```
import random

def display_title():
  print("Guess the number!\n")

def set_limit():
  limit = int(input("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: "))
  return limit

def play_game(limit):
  count = 1
  number = random.randint(1, limit)
  print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
  while True:
    guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
    if guess < number:
      print("Too low. ")
      count += 1
    elif guess > number:
      print("Too high. ")
      count += 1
    elif guess == number: 
      print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
      break

def main(): 
  display_title()
  limit = set_limit()
  play_game(limit)
  again = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
  if again[0].lower() == 'y':
    main()
  else:
    print("Bye!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FoY5/0)

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea. Try changing the >= sign 3 lines above to just > number. Because otherwise it will never get to the "if guess == number" because it will stop for "if guess >= number" every time even if the guess is right.

This is because >= means greater than or equal to.
I really hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! Worded like a charm!